# How to make an image not move from the position when in different resolutions?

Tags: html, css

In the first image you can see the logo is positioned correctly but when I change resolution:

[image]

But when you try it on different resolutions it gets out of the box:

[image]

I just want that when I resize the browser or try in a different resolution, the logo will stay inside the box.

```html
<div class="images">
    <a href="https://www.csgolive.com/affiliates">
        <img src="images/CSGOLive.png" alt="" width="165px" height="63px" style="display: inline-block;no-repeat center fixed; max-height 3.52%: ; max-width: 8.6%; position: absolute; right: 70.5%; bottom: 77%; min-height: 63px; min-width: 165px; height: auto; width: auto;">
    </a>
```

Comment: Did you forget any attribute to use?

Comment: Nope, and i still havent found a solution, I just want to make the image responsive to other resoultions.

Answer (score 0):

To apply different styles when the resolution is above or below a certain threshold, you need to use @media queries in your css.

You can either include a conditional document like this:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />
```

Or add specific styles in the same document like this:

```
    <style>
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
      .gun_icon {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
      }
    }
    </style>
```

This should get you where you need to go:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

You are positioning it absolute which takes the image out of the layout flow.

I'd suggest positioning it absolute to it´s relative parent with px coordinates to avoid percentage/flexible units alterations.

[**Resizable Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/51q0mp0h/3/)

- You have several CSS syntax errors on your inline styles, try to move them to external stylesheet.

Like this:

```
.images {
  /* these 2 just for demo */
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 110px;
  /* new */
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  background: no-repeat center fixed;
  position: absolute;
  /* new */
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  min-height: 63px;
  min-width: 165px;
  height: 63px;
  width: 165px;
}
```

Clean up your HTML, like this (assuming later on you'd close `.images` with a `</div>` tag):

```
<div class="images">
  <a href="https://www.csgolive.com/affiliates">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  </a>
```

**Sizes (red border & .images height is set just for reference):**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Done, but still when I try responsive like smaller resoultion of a monitor the logo changes the place.

Comment: Something else may be pushing it? hard to say with just that code.. in the fiddle it remains static on all sizes.

Answer (score 0):

if you use position: absolute, you must add position:relative; to your parent container.